# Uncaught exception determine source

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

I recently tracked down the source of an exception line by line

```
Try
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ViewHelper before comObj.Send() ");
    comObj.Send();   // a very old com component
    Debug.WriteLine("ViewHelper after  comObj.Send() ");
}
Catch (Exception Ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ViewHelper comObj.Send " + Ex.Message);    
}
```

comObj.Send() was throwing an exception
The exception crashes the app
But it was not caught in the above Try Catch
I had break on all Exceptions in Visual Studio and it was not breaking on that line
It was caught in a global error handler App_DispatcherUnhandledException
If I set e.Handled = true; it is just thrown many times and still crashes the app
The exception gave no information about the source
The only way I found the source was by those before and after debug statements
The exception was thrown in one in a hundred calls so it was hard to track

Was there a better faster way to find the source of the Exception?
It there a way to step back to the last line called?

In hind site I should have focused on the COM components.

Comment: What was it throwing?  It doesn't sound like what it was throwing was really meant to be caught, you might have been better off with an app crash to debug at the point of failure.  (For C++ Assemblies, Code Generation->Enable C++ Exceptions) has a lot of control here.

Comment: @ebyrob if I let it crash out it was not on that line.  Like I said that direct try catch was was not catching it.

Comment: by "crash out" you mean the core-dump didn't contain that line (or memory location) in it-its stack-trace?  (I was also assuming you modified the default handler: http://mike.woelmer.com/2009/04/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-wpf/)

Comment: @ebyrob No if I tried to attach a debugger it was not on that line. How do I examine a core-dump?  And I don't know what you mean by modified the default handler.   Clearly I don't know much about this.

Comment: If you haven't already over-ridden the default unhandled exception handler then follow the link above and do that.  (Just generating a core-dump may require WinDbg, reading them gets quickly harder from there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I suspect that exceptions are being thrown from native code, I enable `debugging of unmanaged code`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> To enable debugging of unmanaged code
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
> 2. Click the Debug tab.
> 3. Select the Enable unmanaged code debugging check box.

This can slow performance so turn it off when not debugging native components.

I'd also break on all exceptions first but you mentioned that you did that, so unmanaged debugging would be the next step for me.

Comment: Yes that got more information. user32.dll!_DdeClientTransaction@32()  + 0x3ac bytes  [External Code].